# Создать json файл с одинаковой структурой

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Ребята незнаю как написать *javascript*, который создает `json` с одинаковой структурой как и в оригинальном файле, но только на одном языке например в `cz-CZ` и естественно чтоб содержал только отсутствующии лейблы.

**P.S** лейблы это все элементы страницы. 
Парсер написал, но опять же незнаю как передать название файла источника и язык источника в качестве входного параметра .

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile('labels.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
    }
console.log(data.toString());
var obj = JSON.parse(data)
fs.writeFile('labels.cz-CZ.json');
});
```

пример самого json файла, в нем лейблы то есть содержание страницы на двух языках, надо чтоб javascript как бы создавал json в котором лейблы только те которые не перевелись или перевода не существует

```
"Shell": {
        "Profile": "Profile",
        "SignOut": "Sign out",
        "CloseView": "Close current view",
        "Settings": "Settings",
        "ModifySettings": "Modify settings",
        "SettingsModified": "Settings have been changed",
        "Help": "Help"
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример исходного файла, и того, что должно из него получиться. Без этого непонятно, чего именно Вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: пардон забыл дописать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вам нужно просто сравнить два объекта.

Предположим мы загрузили два объекта из файлов:

```
var target = JSON.parse(dataDefault);
var current = JSON.parse(dataCZ);
```

Далее сравниваем все проперти, если такой проперти нет или ее значение равно исходному то записываем в результирующий объект:

```
var result = {};
for (var key in target) {
    if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key))
        continue;
    if (target[key] == current[key] || !current[key]) {
        result[key] = target[key];
    }
}
```

Далее сохраняем:

```
fs.writeFile("result.json", JSON.stringify(result));
```

**Обновление:**

Смотрю у вас сложная структура, нужно пройтись по всем вложенным значениям рекурсивно. Можно добавить вот такую функцию:

```
function compare(target, current){
    var result = {};
    for (var key in target) {
        if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key))
            continue;
        if(typeof target[key] == "object"){
            result[key] = compare(target[key], current[key])
        } else {
            if (target[key] == current[key] || !current[key]) {
                result[key] = target[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

И вызвать:

```
fs.writeFile("result.json", JSON.stringify(compare(target, current)));
```

```js
var target = {
 "Shell" : {
  "Profile" : "Profile",
  "SignOut" : "Sign out",
  "CloseView" : "Close current view",
  "Settings" : "Settings",
  "ModifySettings" : "Modify settings",
  "SettingsModified" : "Settings have been changed",
  "Help" : "Help"
 }
}
var current = {
 "Shell" : {
  "Profile" : "Профиль",
  "SignOut" : "Выйти",
  "CloseView" : "",
  "Settings" : "Settings",
  "ModifySettings" : "Дополнительные настройки",
  "Help" : "Помощь"
 }
};

function compare(target, current) {
 var result = {};
 for (var key in target) {
  if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key))
   continue;
  if (typeof target[key] == "object") {
   result[key] = compare(target[key], current[key])
  } else {
   if (target[key] == current[key] || !current[key]) {
    result[key] = target[key];
   }
  }
 }
 return result;
}

console.log(compare(target, current));
```

**Обновление 2**

Ваш код должен выглядеть как то так:

```
// получить третий аргумент из командной строки
var name = process.argv[2];

var defaultName = "en_US";

var file = {/*...*/}

var nfResult = {};

if(!file[name]){
    nfResult = file[name] = name[defaultName];
} else {
    nfResult = compare(name[defaultName], file[name]);
}
```

Comment: можно в чат, чтоб незасорять эфир @CoddWrench

Comment: да вы меня правельно поняли, то есть я должен создать файл который берет как за параметр название json файла, то есть 
    function extract (parametr1, parametr2)
потом читает labels.json только секцию en_US, и проверяет если есть секция cs_CZ если нет то он копирует в файл missing_cs_CZ.json всю секцию en_US, если все же есть то он сравнивает секнию en_US с секцией cs_CZ и те которые отличаются или не существуют записывает в отдельный json

Comment: @t0rick, вы описали что-то слишком сложное и не очевидное, попробуйте разбить на несколько разных вопросов.

Comment: первая задачка, через консоль с помощью node.js запускаю extract-missing-labels.js с параметром labels.json cs_CZ
вторая задачка, этот js проверяет если в структуре файла labels.json есть секция cs_CZ, если нету то копирует секцию en_US из labels.json и вставляет в другой missing-labels.js, если есть то сравнивает секцию в labels.json en_US с cs_CZ, и то что несовпадает пишет в labels.cs_CZ.json который и создает
вроде все разбил на задачки @Codd Wrench

Comment: @t0rick, смотрите второе обновление, думаю дальше сами разберетесь.

Comment: вижу спасибо, щас буду пробовать @Codd Wrench